# Philippines work visa: is it up to the company to do the application or can I do it by myself?

Tags: visa, working-visas, philippines

I'm from the EU and I'm planning to move to Manila and to find a job there.

As far as I understand, I need a job contract and then I need to apply for a 9(G) visa. I tried to do some research, but I'm still a bit confused about how to apply.

These are my questions:

1. Is it up to the company that offers me a job to take care of the visa application, or can I do that by myself?
2. Do I need to be already in the Philippines in order to be able to apply for the visa or can I do it remotely?

Comment: No chance of working in PI as an Expat, unless you do digital nomad. Then you can come in on another visa. Those work visas are for multinational companies who have employees from the home country. No one will hire an Expat.